# Python3 + Boto3. Virtual device MFA. Can't generate QRcode.png

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto, boto3

I have a script with boto3, that creates new virtual MFA divice and enables it. The problem is that I can not create a QR code file. In the boto3 doc page they indicate that response syntax is:

```
{
    'VirtualMFADevice': {
        'SerialNumber': 'string',
        'Base32StringSeed': b'bytes',
        'QRCodePNG': b'bytes',
        'User': {
            'Path': 'string',
            'UserName': 'string',
            'UserId': 'string',
            'Arn': 'string',
            'CreateDate': datetime(2015, 1, 1),
            'PasswordLastUsed': datetime(2015, 1, 1)
        },
        'EnableDate': datetime(2015, 1, 1)
    }
}
```

I can't find the way to convert the output of "QRCodePNG" to an actual QR code .png file.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

Just write the content of QRCodePNG key and it works:

```
with open('qr.png', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(QRCodePNG)
```

This will create an image.